Typescript: Variable being used before assigned - isn't that correct?
Why is the following code invalid in strict mode:
let x: string[];
if (Math.random() > .5){ x = ['x']; }

//TS2454: x possible undefined. Yeah, I know?
return x?.map(v => v);

Yeah, I know that x may be undefined. But that's why I'm using the Optional Chaining Operator. And that sure perfectly works on undefined.

Had you written your code with correct types, it'd not be a problem. But you're just deliberately confusing the compiler by claiming that an unassigned variable is not allowed. Had you instead declared let x: string[] | undefined; you'd have signalled your intention that undefined is an acceptable value.

Can you please create a TS playground to show your error. TS shows different error here : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/DYUwLgBAHgXBDOYBOBLAdgcwNoF0DcAUCgGYQAUAsgIZgAWAdElWgCYD2AtmQJQQB8EegFZuAb2gQAvBCwByKLPwQAvgQJQA-PQ5UADmQBuUgQe54gA

@TusharShahi it's the same error, though? https://i.sstatic.net/4hK4CSRL.png what is the error you're seeing?

Yes taht is what i get, but OP had mentioned //TS2454: x possible undefined. Yeah, I know? so i figured

I think you just need to change this: let x: string[] , to: let x: string[]=[];
Or you can define x with an exclamation mark - thus you tell the compiler that the responsibility is on you: let x!: string[];

The code is invalid in strict mode because TypeScript's strict mode includes the strictNullChecks option, which ensures that variables cannot be used before they are assigned.
In your code, x is declared but not necessarily initialized before it is used in the return statement.
You have then 3 options

Initialize x with a default value

let x: string[] = [];


Use a Type Union with undefined

let x: string[] | undefined;


Add an Else Case to Initialize x

let x: string[];
if (Math.random() > .5) {
   x = ['x'];
} else {
   x = [];
}

return x.map(v => v);


And in addition, there is another possibility to define to the compiler that you take responsibility for the fact that the variable was not assigned - only if you are really sure that this should not cause any problems, and thus it will stop warning about errors of this type:
  let x!: string[];


*few months later, a different developer looks at the code* "Hmm, why is this ?. here?" *checks the type* "Oh, not needed, since it's never nullish. Probably a mistake then." *removes the ? from ?.'* *code starts throwing errors*

Yes, you are absolutely right.
I'll edit the answer and state that it's only in case you're really sure there won't be a problem if your code, and that you've documented it well...

But the types serve as documentation. If your argument really is "It works if you don't use TS at all but try to use other alternatives to it"...well, does it work?

You are right that there are better ones, I just mentioned that there is another option.
for public information.

Thank you for that information! But yeah, stating it might be undefined is way nicer :)
